# Shorthand for enum argument type

Tags: typescript, enums

I have the following enum:

```
enum ApiTypes {
  Main = "MAIN",
  Global = "GLOBAL"
}

export default ApiTypes;
```

I am using its values to restrict what can be passed into certain functions:

```
  getBlah = async (
    type: ApiTypes.Main | ApiTypes.Global
  ) => { ... }
```

This works perfectly well. However what if my enum was huge? Would I have to explicitly write out each item of the enum? Or is there a short way to tell the argument it can be one of any values of an enum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just write the name of the enum, e.g.:

```
getBlah = async (type: ApiTypes) => { ... }
```

From the example in the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#enums):

```
enum Response {
    No = 0,
    Yes = 1,
}

function respond(recipient: string, message: Response): void {
    // ...
}

respond("Princess Caroline", Response.Yes)
```

Comment: Exactly. That's why `enum ApiTypes {...}` creates a definition in the type space in the first place.